# How to Solve this error when I m uploading image in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I m working with MVC with SQL server management studio?

Error: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

I won't know what is the error?

I change in 3 places

1.Index.cshtml

2.create.cshtml

3.CrudManuallyController.cs

public string Image { get; set; } varchar(50)

```
CrudManually Controller:   
    public class CrudManuallyController : Controller
    {
            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                return View();
            }

            // POST: CrudManually/Create
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(manage manages,HttpPostedFileBase image)
            {
                try
                {
                      var folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
                      image.SaveAs(Path.Combine("~/Images/", image.FileName));
                      manages.Image = Path.Combine("~/Images/", image.FileName);

                      // TODO: Add insert logic here
                      db.manages.Add(manages);
                      db.SaveChanges();
                      return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View(manages);
                }
            }
    }
```

```
create.cshtml
    <h2>Create</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CrudManually", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
                </div>
             <div class="editor-field">
                <input id="Image" title="Image Uploading" type="file" name="image" />
            </div>
    }
```

```
Index.cshtml
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               <td>
                 <img src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" alt="Image not display" width="20%" height="20%" />
                </td>
            }
          </tr>
</table>
```

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk2Ue.png)

How to solve this error?
I won't know what is the error? 
any code adds in my program and runs my image uploading successfully What Can I DO?

Image1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCBkn.png)

Comment: there are few mistakes in you're code. otherwise its perfect. so please see my post for your resolution.

Comment: @ankitkanojia I just start a learn MVC can u describe my problem briefly?

Comment: i am drafting the post so please give me 5min, i will explain you.

Comment: please see my another post it work perfect on my machine so please verify on you're side and get resolution for you're requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(manages manages, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    try
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            //using System.IO;
            var folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
            }

            //Path.Combine for concate folder path and image name together
            var imagePathName = Path.Combine(folderPath, image.FileName);
            image.SaveAs(imagePathName);
            manages.Image = image.FileName;
            //TODO: Add insert logic here
            //db.manages.Add(manages);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(manages);
    }
}
```

**create.cshtml code**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        Image
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="Image" title="Image Uploading" type="file" name="image" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="button" />
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               <td>
                 <img src="@Url.Content('~/Images/' + item.Image)" alt="Image not display" width="20%" height="20%" />
                </td>
            }
          </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you change your answer in index.cshtml I miss this line: ``` <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + item.Image)" alt="Image not display" width="20%" height="20%" /> ``` Url.Content it is a string i miss this line and also change your code thanks for given suggestion. and also uncomment this line : ```db.manages.Add(manages);``` very helpful for me thanks sir for your suggestion

Comment: Yes, basically i just refactor the code of uploading functionality. so left the display part of index.cshtml !! Ha ha.

Comment: Its good that you have got you're resolution.. Thank you.. Keep Coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

**CrudManually Controller**

```
//replace HttpPostedFile with HttpPostedFileBase object
//please add server.Mappath function into code for exact foler structure to save file
public class CrudManuallyController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CrudManually/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(manage manages,HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            try
            {
                var folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
                image.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folderPath, image.FileName));
                manages.Image= Path.Combine(folderPath, image.FileName);
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                db.manages.Add(manages);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(manages);
            }
        }
}
```

**create.cshtml**

```
//encytype is wrong please replace it with enctype
//input file name="file" so it will not set on controller side as its name on controller side is 'image', so you need to repalce name='file' with name='image'

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CrudManually", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input id="Image" title="Image Uploading" type="file" name="image" />
            </div>
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               <td>
                   <img src="@Url.Content('~/Images/' + item.Image)" alt="Image not display" width="20%" height="20%" />
                </td>
            }
          </tr>
</table>
```

**Explaination :**

ASP.NET C# MVC provides the facility of HttpPostedFileBase class is an abstract class that contains the same members as the HttpPostedFile class. so we can use this abstract class while work with uploading file onto server.

Step 1: For that, we need to use input type of file with **name attribute**.

Step 2: Form must be POST with **enctype = "multipart/form-data"**

Step 3: On the controller side we need to get HttpPostedFileBase object value with the same name which we already gave to input file type

```
public ActionResult Create(manage manages,HttpPostedFileBase image)
```

Step 4: After follow all the steps on Form post you will get the value of file in the image object of type HttpPostedFileBase and then you need to check the nullable condition and simply code foe save the file.

```
var virtualPath = StaticValues.AdvertisementImagePath;
var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
Utilities.SaveFile(fileObject, virtualPath, physicalPath, "FILE PATH");
```

Comment: It would help everyone a lot more if you explained what you have changed, and why

Comment: @ADyson, sure will explain with edited post, in a few minutes

Comment: @ankitkanojia thanks for support but still facing this issue I change my code

Comment: let me share you exact code which i performed in my local machine so that you can get an idea

Comment: @rahulpatil may I need to remove this post or leave it as it is for instruction purposes. as I have already shared instructions with the post.